# Half-wave rectifier output graph

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I want to know what will be the output V-t  graph when you connect a half-wave rectifier to a battery using an inverter instead of a traditional AC source? Because when I tried it, the output graph was inverted, not what I was expecting (I was expecting the graph to be similar to the graph when we connect it to a traditional AC source). Why this happens?
Was I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are asking why rectified dc does not look like rectified ac, I think you need to step back and think about diodes and incoming voltages.

Comment: Nope, I mean DC converted to AC using an inverter before connecting to the circuit.